# Datatable jquery paging and colreorder

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Hi I am using Dragtable jquery library, 
I see that you can customize paging section by modifying the sDom property.

```
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sPaginationType": "four_button",
                "bFilter": false,
                "sDom": '<"top"lp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"i<"clear">>'
            } );
```

I wish to include the colreorder feature as well to this table. I know the sDom for that is....

```
"sDom": 'Rlfrtip'
```

How do i include this so  that I have both the sDom feature in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put R in the starting position of sDom:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "sPaginationType": "four_button",
    "bFilter": false,
    "sDom": 'R<"top"lp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"i<"clear">>'
} );
```

http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom explains how to use the sDom property. To enable the colResorder it just puts an R at start where (lfrtip) is the default. That is what i also did, i preserved your ordering in the question.

These are the explanations for the other letters:

```
'l' - Length changing
'f' - Filtering input 
't' - The table!
'i' - Information
'p' - Pagination
'r' - pRocessing
```